# Setting an alarm from inside another alarm using AlarmManager class not getting fired correctly

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

The below code is from my MainActivity onCreate() method where I set an alarm to run a service ScheduleAlarm immediately and only once. sPrefs is the SharedPreference object that takes care of setting this alarm only once. The service ScheduleAlarm is an IntentService which is getting fired perfectly.

```
if(sPrefs.getBoolean("SettingAlarmForFirstTime",true)) {
        //Creating alarm for showing notifications.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScheduleAlarms.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);//Use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY instead of int number here.
        editor.putBoolean("SettingAlarmForFirstTime", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Now this is my ScheduleAlarms service class. When this service is started onHandleIntent() method is called from where I am calling setWeeklyAlarms() method. Now my problem is from inside this method I want to set 7 alarms for a complete week based on timings that I will obtain from an API server call. Right now I am unable to even execute a single alarm perfectly. The alarm that i am setting is set to start after 3 secs delay which will call another service named NotificationService but the alarms gets fired immediately instead of waiting for 3 secs. Please analyze and tell me why this is happening.

```
public class ScheduleAlarms extends IntentService {
private boolean notificationsEnabled = true;
private String notificationTimings = "";

public ScheduleAlarms() {
    super("ScheduleAlarms");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    setWeeklyAlarm();
}

private void setWeeklyAlarm() {
    Intent i = new Intent(ScheduleAlarms.this, NotificationService.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ScheduleAlarms.this, 10001, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ScheduleAlarms.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

/* Setting this alarmManager to fire up the alarm after 3 mins delay, but this alarm is getting fired immediately*/

```
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 3*60*1000, pendingIntent);


}
```

}

Comment: check my answer below. The full code is here: https://github.com/Shiza1aas/dailyQuranVerses/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/shiza/dailyquranverses/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 3*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

to:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis() + 3 * 60 * 1000, 3 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

The alarm is fired up immediately, because

> AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP + 0, ...

So, the first time, it is fired up after 0 seconds. To change this, you need to add some time here.

```
AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP + time
```

And, also it should be repeating, so you need to use `setRepeating`.

Note : `3 * 60 * 1000 == 3 minutes, not 3 seconds`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, am checking it out.

Comment: It works.. Thanks. One more thing what actually I am trying to achieve is that I want to set alarms for a week where each day has its own timings that I obtain by making a server call. The server returns a string in the form "0,08:00;1,09:00;2,18:30;3,08:00;4,08:45;5,09:45;5,10:00" where ; is the delimiter and substring like the first 0,08:00 signifies 0->Sunday 08->Hour of the day and 00-> Minutes. Now what logic should i implement?

Comment: Should I set 7 alarms inside setWeeklyAlarm() method and when each alarm is fired up then i again call this ScheduleAlarm service and update the 7 alarms or is there any other better solution to what I want to acheive?

Comment: Should I set 7 alarms inside setWeeklyAlarm() method : this is a very bad idea. Take the string from server, check for today, suppose its sunday then get the first part and process it accordingly.

Comment: You should use a different method for alarmcreation, whenever some conditions is true, just call the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84244/discussion-between-learner-and-rohit).